# Users will enter dates in my cocoa (core data) app. How to choose right date format?

Tags: validation, cocoa, core-data, user-input

I am working on my first application for mac which uses Core Data. Since I don't have much software development experience I would like to ask the more experienced developers the following question:

When entering data in some of the forms, user will have to enter a date in couple of the forms. Since app will be on app store and people from different continents will download it (I hope so) I am thinking of allowing the user to select his preferred date format from the preferences panel that I have in my app.

But I am wondering what will happen if after entering 500 or more records, he decide to change the date format again? Will that cause  a mess in core data eventually?

Is this good idea or I should keep things simple and just get the system date (user computer date format) and use that date format?  What would you do? Any advice will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to keep date as timeinterval. You can see such method for [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDate/timeIntervalSince1970).

```
The interval between the date object and 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.
```

So if you get NSDate object from NSDatFormatter object you will be able to obtain time in seconds since 1970. You could store this value in Core Data and use it later for [creating NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:) objects. You will be able to use it for different locales and time zones as well as use the correct format. 
*'Dates'* is complex topic and I suggest you to read guides about [dates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039-SW1) and [date formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1).

Comment: I already start the reading on this topic, but for the moment I know one thing for sure, I will need just the date, without the time. If I accept the date as timeinterval I do get more freedom in later eventual data manipulation, but same doubt remain...in which format I should display the date? Can user choose his preffered format If I save the data as timeinterval? How difficult will that be to write in objective-c? I am afraid that I am not the best & brightest objective-c programmer. In many situations, I struggle on basic things....

Comment: `Can user choose his preffered format If I save the data as timeinterval? How difficult will that be to write in objective-c?`
Yes, you will be able to display the date in preferred format. Timeinterval is an absolute point in time and you can create appropriate date in any timezone using it. Also you can use NSDateFormatter to configure string for  preferred format. I've remembered one more [exciting article](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/11/working-with-date-and-time-in-cocoa-part-1/) by Ole Bigemann. It's written in more human language the apple docs. It must help you.

Answer (score 1):

First is to decide how you should store the date. The answer here is as an NSDate. The NSDate is a single unique precise point in time, thus it in a sense stores both date and time.

This means that for example 1 PM in Berlin and 8 pm in Kuala Lumpur will be the exact same NSDate value (during winter months) but 2 pm in London and 2 pm in Paris the same calendar date will not be the same NSDate value. This is a quite complex topic, read the date and time programming topics documentation from Apple.

Then as you say you need to allow you user to input the date. The way to do that is to use a NSDateFormatter tied to your input control. The formatter can be defined to be as per system settings, which means you will get the localisation you are seeking for free, so that is in fact easy.

The tricky thing you are really facing is to determine what you are really looking to store if it is only the calendar date without an associated time you want to store. For example you decide store the date combined with 12.00 noon in the local timezone. Then if the user shifts to another timezone more than 12 hours away the date may be displayed as the previous date or the next. The safest bet is to store the date combined with 12:00 noon GMT as this is in the middle of the time zone range. There are a few locations 13 and 14 hours off that could exhibit the mentioned problem anyway, but these are small atolls in the pacific and could possibly be safely ignored.

However the the best thing is if you can in fact determine that what you are looking to store is really a precise point in time rather than a date (which is a 24 hour fuzzy definition). For example in a  calendar app an event usually takes place at a specific time on a specific date, then store that time and date.

Comment: I am 100% sure that I need to store just the date, without the time. I am not that good at objective c as I would like to be, so I am seeing as an easy solution NSDateFormatter which will somehow get the user computer date format and format the date in the same manner. Maybe better solution will arise from some other answer, we will see.

Comment: In that case I would certainly go with a NSDate and 12 noon in GMT/UTC for each date.  It is pretty easy to set up a date formatter for an input control in IB that delivers a NSDate. Set the date format to user default, set the input to date components only. Set time as default 12:00 and time zone as GMT. That way you will have a constant date record that is easy to manipulate and you can use all the date comparison tools that already exist. It can alos easily be extended to even other calendars.

Comment: I don't understand why would I bother to enter time at all...User enter certain date, without time. Record will be saved in core data as date. Next time, when this record is displayed, I want to show the same date that has been entered by the user. My only doubt is should I allow the user to choose the date format from "preferences" panel that I have built for my app, or just to get his computer date format, and display all the dates in my app as they are displayed on his computer. Same is true for the time zone. Is there any reason why I must enter time and time zone?

Comment: The topic is complex and I advice reading the Apple time and date documents. In simple terms the NSDate class stores a precise point in time with subsecond precision. One such point may be one date in Tokyo and another in New York due to time zones. If you want to be able to compare dates to see if they are same and are not interested in the time but just the date then the solution is to always store a default time with each date. That default time should be noon GMT to ensure (almost) guaranteed that all users see same day/month/year irrespective of which time zone they are in.